# No document found for query xxx on model xxx

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I get the error you can read it from the title. It appears whenever i try to `.save()` a document.

```
let [post] = (
    await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: USER_ID },
      {
        $push: {
          posts: {
            title,
            content,
            userId: USER_ID,
            titleUrl,
            thumbnail: {
              webp: WEBP_PATH,
              jpeg: JPEG_PATH,
              placeholder: PLACEHOLDER
            }
          }
        }
      },
      { new: true }
    )
  ).posts.slice(-1);
  let newBlog = new Blog(post);
  await newBlog.save();
```

What i tried:

`newBlog.update()` no error appeard, but also no change.

I also tried to set a different version key at my model like `{  versionKey: "_someKey"}` no success.

What could it be?

`await Blog.create(post)` also didnt work. Same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the people that are in the same situation, my solution was adding `.lean()` at the end of the query

```
let [post] = (
    await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: USER_ID },
      {
        $push: {
          posts: {
            title,
            content,
            userId: USER_ID,
            titleUrl,
            thumbnail: {
              webp: WEBP_PATH,
              jpeg: JPEG_PATH,
              placeholder: PLACEHOLDER
            }
          }
        }
      },
      { new: true }
    ).lean()
  ).posts.slice(-1);
```